# How to create a startup service of django for ubuntu server?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-server, startupscript

I am creating a project where I am using an ubuntu server for production.

I need to run the server in the background even though I log out. So, as a solution I am using screen but however if I restart it won't work as we all know and I have to rewrite the screen commands.

So, I want to use the startup service but somehow I am lost in that as I have no idea how to do that.[here](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/) is the one way to write the script and I love it but how to add the command

```
python manage.py runserver [IP Address]
```

in this service.

Sorry if I sound so silly but I need a quick and useful solution, so I thought to be here.

Thanks if anyone can guide me on it.

Comment: You should [*not*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver) use `runserver`  in production - it is intended only for development. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/) explains what you need for deployment.

Comment: Thanks @solarissmoke Let me read the documention